# Show shortcuts in Windows Explorer tree (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, shortcuts, tree-view

Answer is probably no but still want to check:

I often use Windows Explorer with the treeview on the left (what you get when you hit Windows-E) to switch between folders.
On my desktop I have a couple of shortcuts to often visited network locations. Can I get those to display in the tree as well? Now it only displays 'real' folders, not the shortcuts to folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it IS possible to cutomise the links that appear on the side-bar in Windows Explorer in Windows XP.

There is an excellent guide on the forums at [pcreview.](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/adding-shortcuts-sidebar-open-file-dialog-box-t3056794.html) Check out the first reply.